# Propel2: lowercase/camelCase keys when converting ObjectCollection toJSON()

Tags: php, json, propel, camelcasing, propel2

How can we convert the keys of a toJson() returned object to lowercase or camelCase?
Consider the following example:

Query:

```
     $foo = FooQuery::create()
        ->filterByBar($bar)
        ->findOne()
        ->toJson();
```

Result:

```
{"Id": 1, "Bar":"StackOverflow"}
```

It seems to be PascalCase by default.
How can I get lowercase properties on the json result?

The function I'm referring to can be found [here and is applied to an ObjectCollection.](http://api.propelorm.org/2.0-master/Propel/Runtime/Collection/ObjectCollection.html#method_toJSON)

**Update:**
I want to avoid using arrays as: array_change_key_case() does not work for multidimensional arrays when dealing with complex objects.

I know this can be achieved through some modifications but I want to know if there's a better approach, preferably without casting to an array first for performance purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to configure your generated classes to use camelCase keys.  In your propel.json (or .yaml, .php .ini .xml) configuration file add the objectModel as follows:

```
"generator": {
  "defaultConnection": "bookstore",
  "connections": [ "bookstore" ],
  "objectModel": {
    "defaultKeyType": "camelName"
  }
}
```

This will make all your keys camelCased but it turns out that this only works with the `toArray()` method.  When you call `toJSON()` you're actually using the `exportTo('JSON')` method.  If you look at the `exportTo` method you can see that it is calling:

```
$this->toArray(TableMap::TYPE_PHPNAME, $includeLazyLoadColumns, array(), true)
```

This is forcing `exportTo('JSON')` and `toJSON()` to use `TableMap::TYPE_PHPNAME` as the key type.  If you look at the `toArray` method definition it uses your `"defaultKeyType"` as the default `$keyType`.  If you call `toArray()` without any parameters and you have `"defaultKeyType": "camelName"` then it will use `TableMap::TYPE_CAMELNAME` and therefore return all the keys as camelCase.

The root of the problem is in Propel's generator classes.  The base classes are generated in
`propel/src/Propel/Generator/Builder/Om/ObjectBuilder.php`
If we look at how it generates the `toArray` method we find:

```
public function toArray(\$keyType = TableMap::$defaultKeyType, \$includeLazyLoadColumns = true, \$alreadyDumpedObjects = array()" . ($hasFks ? ", \$includeForeignObjects = false" : '') . ")
```

The important point here is that it is using `TableMap::$defaultKeyType`.  Now if we look at `exportTo` method generation we have to look in `templates/baseObjectMethods.php` and the exportTo method definition is as follows:

```
public function exportTo($parser, $includeLazyLoadColumns = true)
{
    if (!$parser instanceof AbstractParser) {
        $parser = AbstractParser::getParser($parser);
    }

    return $parser->fromArray($this->toArray(TableMap::TYPE_PHPNAME, $includeLazyLoadColumns, array(), true));
}
```

The important point here is that it uses the hardcoded value `TableMap::TYPE_PHPNAME`.  If you change that hardcoded value to `TableMap::TYPE_CAMELNAME` and regenerate your classes then `toJSON()` will give all keys as camelCase.

So unfortunately you cannot make `toJSON` use camelCase without modifying the source.  I would think that the `exportTo` method should use the `defaultKeyType` so we can use the configuration to modify this behavior.  That being said there may be a perfectly good reason to have the hardcoded value instead of a configurable value.

**Update:**
It looks like this only works with a single instance of each of the generated model classes.  With the `ObjectCollection` and `Collection` classes the `toArray` and `exportTo` methods use hardcoded values of `TableMap::TYPE_PHPNAME`

Propel/Runtime/Collection/Collection.php

```
public function exportTo($parser, $usePrefix = true, $includeLazyLoadColumns = true)
{
    if (!$parser instanceof AbstractParser) {
        $parser = AbstractParser::getParser($parser);
    }

    $array = $this->toArray(null, $usePrefix, TableMap::TYPE_PHPNAME, $includeLazyLoadColumns);

    return $parser->listFromArray($array, lcfirst($this->getPluralModelName()));
}
```

Propel/Runtime/Collection/ObjectCollection.php

```
public function toArray($keyColumn = null, $usePrefix = false, $keyType = TableMap::TYPE_CAMELNAME, $includeLazyLoadColumns = true, $alreadyDumpedObjects = [])
{
    $ret = [];
    $keyGetterMethod = 'get' . $keyColumn;

    /** @var $obj ActiveRecordInterface */
    foreach ($this->data as $key => $obj) {
        $key = null === $keyColumn ? $key : $obj->$keyGetterMethod();
        $key = $usePrefix ? ($this->getModel() . '_' . $key) : $key;
        $ret[$key] = $obj->toArray($keyType, $includeLazyLoadColumns, $alreadyDumpedObjects, true);
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

So once again it would be nice if we could use the configuration file to set these to `TableMap::CAMELNAME` but unfortunately that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

### For changing the behavior every time

I don't think Propel gives you a direct easy way to do this via an option you pass in to the method. You can, however, override `*Base` methods in your classes.

```
public function toJSON() {
  $fields = array_change_key_case(parent::toJSON());
  return $fields;
}
```

### For one-off case changes

Still using the function above but with more detail: `array_change_key_case` changes the case of all keys in an array. You can read about it in the [PHP official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php).

> `array_change_key_case ( array $array [, int $case = CASE_LOWER ] )`
>   Returns an array with all keys from array lowercased or uppercased.
>   Numbered indices are left as is.

**Parameters**

array
The array to work on

case
Either CASE_UPPER or CASE_LOWER (default)

**Return Values**

Returns an array with its keys lower or uppercased, or FALSE if array is not an array.

Works in **(PHP 4 >= 4.2.0, PHP 5, PHP 7)**

**Example**

```
<?php
$input_array = array("FirSt" => 1, "SecOnd" => 4);
print_r(array_change_key_case($input_array, CASE_UPPER));
?>
```

**Outputs**

```
Array
(
    [FIRST] => 1
    [SECOND] => 4
)
```

**For you...**

In your example, you could simply type `$lower_foo = array_change_key_case($foo);` on the next line since lowercase is the default.

Comment: Thanks for the input but I already know about array_change_key_case. I want to integrate it into the propel query so that I don't have to convert my results for every single db call.

Comment: @scripton I don't think propel provides the option, but if you override the base class's  JSON method, it's only a single line of code and does what you want. I edited my answer to mention that. You could also decode the JSON, add another custom property, and re-encode. (That's not useful to you here, but I think it's the more common reason to override this.)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried using that function in my EntityQuery class but that did not seem to work as the parent does not have that function. Where exactly in which Propel class(es) would I need to add that function?